# PostgreSQL - set a default cell value according to another cell value

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers, default-value, postgresql-9.2

If i have a column say `column a` of any given values, and i want another column `column b`  to have a `default value` according to the value of `column a`

In another words:
if `column a = 'peter'` then `column b default value = 'doctor'`.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is **not possible** with a simple `DEFAULT` value, as [the manual clearly states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> The value is any variable-free expression (subqueries and
> cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed).

You could use a [**trigger**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) instead:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_foo_b_default()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- For just a few constant options, CASE does the job:
   NEW.b := CASE NEW.a
               WHEN 'peter'  THEN 'doctor'
               WHEN 'weirdo' THEN 'shrink'
               WHEN 'django' THEN 'undertaker'
            -- ELSE null default
            END;

   /*
   -- For more, or dynamic options, consider a lookup table:
   SELECT INTO NEW.b  t.b
   FROM   def_tbl t
   WHERE  t.a = NEW.a;
   */

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;


CREATE TRIGGER b_default
BEFORE INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.b IS NULL AND NEW.a IS NOT NULL)
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_foo_b_default();
```

For Postgres 10 or older use the `EXECUTE PROCEDURE ...` instead. See:

- [Trigger function does not exist, but I am pretty sure it does](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255319/3684)

To make it more efficient use a `WHEN` clause in the trigger definition (available since Postgres 9.0). This way the trigger function is only executed when it's actually useful. (Assuming we can let `b IS NULL` slide if `a IS NULL`.)

In Postgres 12 or later, a `GENERATED` column may be the better solution. See [jian's added answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69569932/939860). Note, however, these restrictions in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> The generation expression can refer to other columns in the table, but
> not other generated columns. Any functions and operators used must be
> immutable. References to other tables are not allowed.

This trigger is **subtly different from a `DEFAULT` value** in that null in `b` is always replaced with the value derived from `a`, while a `DEFAULT` is just the default and can be overruled with any explicit input.
A `GENERATED` column does not allow input to begin with.

Answer (score 23):

In PostgreSQL 12 or later we can use **Generated Columns**.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html
example:

```
create temp table foo (
  a text,
  b text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      case WHEN a = 'telegram' THEN 'im'
           WHEN a = 'proton' THEN 'email'
           WHEN a = 'infinity' THEN 'idea'
           ELSE 'bad idea'
      end) stored
);
```

--Test time.

```
insert into foo(a) values ('infinity'); 
insert into foo(a) values ('infinity1');
```

returns;

```
   a     |    b
-----------+----------
 infinity1 | bad idea
 infinity  | idea
```

When you try to `insert into foo(b) values ('infinity1')` yield Errors.

```
--ERROR:  cannot insert into column "b" DETAIL:  Column "b" is a generated column.
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and definitely the preferred solution for PostgreSQL 12 onward. Thanks!

Comment: While useful, this one is not really a DEFAULT because you cannot insert on the column.  Trying to change it to `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` while yield a `ERROR:  for a generated column, GENERATED ALWAYS must be specified`.