# with migration to fill slug with default value

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, slugify

In my Laravel 5.6/PostgreSQL 10.5 application 
I have 2 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE public.rt_genres (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    published bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT rt_genres_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)...

CREATE TABLE public.rt_genre_translations (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    genre_id int4 NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    locale varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT genre_translations_genre_id_locale_unique UNIQUE (genre_id, locale),
    CONSTRAINT rt_genre_translations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT genre_translations_genre_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES rt_genres(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I need to add slug field in first rt_genres table
with migration rule:

```
    $table->string('slug', 105)->unique();
```

and got error :

```
: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  could not create unique index "genres_slug_unique"                                          
DETAIL:  Key (slug)=(id) is duplicated.")
```

1)If there is a way to assign in migration some unique default value, like = id 
->default('rt_genres.id')
?

2) That would be cool to assign to slug value from public.rt_genre_translations.name as I use
"cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.5" plugin in my app ? Can I do it ?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there already data in the table?

Comment: yes, these rows call errors...

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the default value from a different column with a trigger ([SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754952/4848587)).

You can make the column `nullable`:

```
$table->string('slug', 105)->nullable()->unique();
```

Or you create the column, insert unique values and then create the index:

```
Schema::table('rt_genres', function($table) {
    $table->string('slug', 105);
});
DB::table('rt_genres')->update(['slug' => DB::raw('"id"')]);
Schema::table('rt_genres', function($table) {
    $table->unique('slug');
});
```