# Does SQL allows addition and subtractions in column?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose, I want to create a table called payment. after that, I want to create three columns in it. selling price, cost price, and then I want to create a profit column like profit = (selling_price - cost_price).  Is it possible and if how?

CREATE TABLE payment(
selling_price NUMERIC,
cost_price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
profit = (selling_price - cost_price),/****   3rd column profit i want to create

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the function you said does not exist in old versions of PostgreSQL. Instead you can create `trigger` for your table.

```
CREATE TABLE payment(
    selling_price NUMERIC,
    cost_price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    profit numeric
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_function()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
   NEW.profit := NEW.selling_price - NEW.cost_price;       
   RETURN NEW;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;;


CREATE TRIGGER payment_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON payment
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_function();
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=76c907405caf3d108d4fb650255ce22e).
Original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737738/postgresql-set-a-default-cell-value-according-to-another-cell-value/16754952#16754952)