# PostgreSQL - set a default cell value according to another Id cell value (autogenerated)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

There is a requirement to have a Postgres table with multiple columns to store audit records.

The table has an Id column populated using autogenerator from sequence(hibernate) for every save. For some purpose, there is a need to have another non-null column added to the table with **DEFAULT** value as copy of the value from autogenerated Id column (but also allows taking the value when explicitly set).

Found few suggestions - [PostgreSQL - set a default cell value according to another cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737738/postgresql-set-a-default-cell-value-according-to-another-cell-value) , still would like to explore if this can be handled at hibernate/Spring JPA level **OR** even at column definition level?

Comment: It could be done by a trigger, always is faster and more secure to maintain all the operations concerning to a database in the database itself rather than in application logic.

Comment: There is no other way than a trigger, at least on the database level.

Comment: My [answer to the referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754952/939860)  still stands for Postgres 15. I suppose this is a duplicate then?